# puppet: iterate over hash which has an array for particular values

Tags: arrays, hash, puppet, erb

I have a hash, built from yaml via stdlib, which includes arrays within the hash. Here is a sample of the yaml:

```
datacenter1:
  propertyA:
    - associatedItem
  cage1:
    serviceA:
    - server1
    - server2
    serviceB:
    - server10
    backupCage:
      cage2
  cage2:
   serviceA:
    - server3
    - server4
    - server5
   serviceB:
    - server11
   backupCage:
     cage1
datacenter2:
  cage1:
    serviceA:
    - server20
    - server21
datacenter3:
  propertyZ:
    serviceD:
    - server200
    - server201
```

in this case I need to get a list of servers which offer a service within a particular datacenter in erb. Ultimately this is just going to need to output in text with some arbitrary data added for an conf file. I'm trying to get all servers providing serviceA for a given datacenter, in this example for datacenter1:

```
thiscommand blahblah server1 
thiscommand blahblah server2
thiscommand blahblah server3
thiscommand blahblah server4
thiscommand blahblah server5
```

I use this map extensively for a variety of things, but this is the first case in which i can't just set a variable in puppet and iterate over that as a single array in erb.

EDIT1:
This data comes from puppet but i am trying to use it in erb via template().

EDIT2:
Note this code would never run against datacenter3, since this code is specific to datacenters which run serviceA.

Edit3:
This is the form that ended up working:
     <% @hash['datacenter1'].values.each do |v| %>

```
 <%- if v.is_a?(Hash) and v.has_key?('serviceA') -%> 

   <% v['serviceA'].each do |myservice| %>

         thiscommand blah blah <%= myservice -%> 

     <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear if you are trying to do this within Puppet or Ruby, so here is how to do it within both.

Puppet:

```
$hash['datacenter1'].each |$dc_key, $dc_nest_hash| {
  if $dc_nest_hash['serviceA'] {
    $dc_nest_hash['serviceA'].each |$serviceA_element| {
      notify { "thiscommand blahblah ${serviceA_element}": }
    }
  }
}
```

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/function.html#each

Ruby in ERB before passed through Puppet `template` function (comments are elucidation for this answer; remove before actually forming template):

```
<% @hash['datacenter1'].each do |_, dc_nest_hash| -%>
  # contents of each datacenter1 nested hash in dc_nest_hash and iterate over each hash
  <%- if dc_nest_hash.key?('serviceA') -%>
    <%- dc_nest_hash['serviceA'].each do |serviceA_element| -%>
      # lookup serviceA key in each dc_nest_hash and iterate over elements
      thiscommand blahblah <%= serviceA_element %>
    <%- end -%>
  <%- end -%>>
<% end -%>
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-enum_for

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each

Comment: This data comes from puppet but i am trying to use it in erb. Using what you wrote as a starting point I almost have it working with the edits (mostly more 'dos') which I posted above.

Comment: still not happy with that syntax: 
`-:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
;  @hash['datacenter1'].each |cage_key, cage_values| do `

 the error carrot is at the space separating cage_key and cage_values

Comment: Failed to parser template <path> .erb at line 7. Line 7 is:
`<%- service_array.each do |service_element| -%>`
    Detail: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Once I get this going, I can wrap another loop around for each datacenter name, I assume.

Comment: @pozcircuitboy I just took your yaml and my code and confirmed it outputs exactly what you are looking for. Is something different between the question and your situation? For example, you just said you have multiple `datacenter` keys, which is not in the yaml in the question.

Comment: I just saw that you updated your code once that I missed. It works syntactically but doesn't select only serviceA; it's returning all arrays under any service. 

I updated the yaml to reflect some of the complications the full map would introduce: multiple services and some properties that aren't of the same data structure; as well as the reality that there are multiple datacenters that i will have to loop through.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I've confirmed your hunch. In the full data, there exists datacenters without this service, as well as information other than nodes. I will update with further data examples above.

Comment: @pozcircuitboy Ok I can update the answer yet again, but please make sure this time the question is actually representing your sitiuation so I don't have to keep updating the answer.

Comment: i ended up taking a slightly different approach which I posted as an edit above. however thank you so much for helping me -- I now understand how to deal with these problems in hashes, based on seeing how you thought through the problem.